# gsub string before first number with upper and lowercase characters

Tags: r

Remove everything after the first number. The data I have looks like:

```
[1] NA                                   "ITEM 1. BUSINESS"                  
[3] "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS"              "ITEM 1B. UNRESOLVED STAFF COMMENTS"
[5] "ITEM 2. PROPERTIES"                 "ITEM 3. LEGAL PROCEEDINGS"
```

I am trying to keep so that I have

```
NA           ITEM1
ITEM1A      ITEM1B
ITEM2       ITEM3
```

(or even keeping the spaces between ITEM 1, ITEM 2 etc.)

I have tried the following without any luck.

```
x <- toupper(x)
x <- gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]]","", x)
x <- gsub(" ", "", x)
x <- substr(x, start = 1, stop = 7)
x <- gsub("\\[digits]*","", x)
```

Also tried:

```
    y <- str_extract(x, "Item")
y <- str_extract(toupper(words$item), "ITEM")
```

Data:

```
c(NA, "ITEM 1. BUSINESS", "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS", "ITEM 1B. UNRESOLVED STAFF COMMENTS", 
"ITEM 2. PROPERTIES", "ITEM 3. LEGAL PROCEEDINGS", "ITEM 4. MINE SAFETY DISCLOSURES", 
"ITEM 5. MARKET FOR REGISTRANT’S COMMON EQUITY, RELATED STOCKHOLDER MATTERS AND ISSUER PURCHASES OF EQUITY SECURITIES", 
"ITEM 6. SELECTED FINANCIAL DATA ", "ITEM 7. MANAGEMENT’S DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS OF FINANCIAL CONDITION AND RESULTS OF OPERATIONS ", 
"ITEM 7A. QUANTITATIVE AND QUALITATIVE DISCLOSURES ABOUT MARKET RISK", 
"ITEM 8. FINANCIAL STATEMENTS AND SUPPLEMENTARY DATA", "ITEM 9. CHANGES IN AND DISAGREEMENTS WITH ACCOUNTANTS ON ACCOUNTING AND FINANCIAL DISCLOSURE", 
"ITEM 9A. CONTROLS AND PROCEDURES", "ITEM 9B.  OTHER INFORMATION", 
"ITEM 10. DIRECTORS, EXECUTIVE OFFICERS AND CORPORATE GOVERNANCE", 
"ITEM 11. EXECUTIVE COMPENSATION", "ITEM 12. SECURITY OWNERSHIP OF CERTAIN BENEFICIAL OWNERS AND MANAGEMENT AND RELATED STOCKHOLDER MATTERS", 
"ITEM 13. CERTAIN RELATIONSHIPS AND RELATED TRANSACTIONS, AND DIRECTOR INDEPENDENCE", 
"ITEM 14. PRINCIPAL ACCOUNTING FEES AND SERVICES", "ITEM 15. EXHIBITS, FINANCIAL STATEMENT SCHEDULE", 
"Item 1.    Business", "Item 1A.    Risk Factors", "Item 1B.    Unresolved Staff Comments", 
"Item 2.    Properties", "Item 3.    Legal Proceedings", "Item 4.    Mine Safety Disclosure", 
"Item 5.    Market for Registrant’s Common Equity, Related Stockholder Matters and Issuer Purchases of Equity Securities", 
"Item 6.    Selected Financial Data", "Item 7.    Management’s Discussion and Analysis of Financial Condition and Results of Operations", 
"Item 7A.    Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures About Market Risk", 
"Item 8.    Financial Statements and Supplementary Data", "Item 9.    Changes in and Disagreements with Accountants on Accounting and Financial Disclosure", 
"Item 9A.    Controls and Procedures", "Item 9B.    Other Information", 
"Item 10.    Directors, Executive Officers and Corporate Governance", 
"Item 11.    Executive Compensation", "Item 12.    Security Ownership of Certain Beneficial Owners and Management and Related Stockholder Matters", 
"Item 13.    Certain Relationships and Related Transactions, and Director Independence", 
"Item 14.    Principal Accountant Fees and Services", "Item 15.    Exhibits and Financial Statement Schedules(a)(1) and (2).  The following documents have been included in Part II, Item 8. Report of Ernst & Young LLP, Independent Registered Public Accounting Firm, on Financial Statements Consolidated Statements of Financial Position — As of December 31, 2017 and 2016 Consolidated Statements of Income — Years Ended December 31, 2017, 2016 and 2015 Consolidated Statements of Comprehensive Income — Years Ended December 31, 2017, 2016 and 2015 Consolidated Statements of Shareholders’ Equity — Years Ended December 31, 2017, 2016 and 2015 Consolidated Statements of Cash Flows — Years Ended December 31, 2017, 2016 and 2015 Notes to Consolidated Financial Statements", 
"Item 1.  Business.", "Item 1A.  Risk Factors.", "Item 1B.  Unresolved Staff Comments.", 
"Item 2.  Properties.", "Item 3.  Legal Proceedings.", "Item 4.  Mine Safety Disclosures.", 
"Item 5.  Market for Registrant's Common Equity, Related Stockholder Matters and Issuer Purchases of Equity Securities.", 
"Item 6.  Selected Financial Data.", "Item 7.  Management's Discussion and Analysis of Financial Condition and Results of Operations. ", 
"Item 7A.  Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures About Market Risk.", 
"Item 8.  Financial Statements and Supplementary Data.", "Item 9.  Changes in and Disagreements with Accountants on Accounting and Financial Disclosure.", 
"Item 9A.  Controls and Procedures.", "Item 9B.  Other Information.", 
"Item 10.  Directors, Executive Officers and Corporate Governance.", 
"Item 11.  Executive Compensation.", "Item 12.  Security Ownership of Certain Beneficial Owners and Management and Related Stockholder Matters.", 
"Item 13.  Certain Relationships and Related Transactions, and Director Independence.", 
"Item 14.  Principal Accounting Fees and Services.", "Item 15.  Exhibits, Financial Statement Schedules.", 
"Item 16. Form 10-K Summary.", "Item 4.    Mine Safety Disclosures", 
"Item 4A.    Executive Officers", "Item 5.    Market for the Registrant's Common Equity, Related Stockholder Matters and Issuer Purchases of Equity Securities", 
"Item 6.    Selected Financial Data", "Item 7.   Management's Discussion and Analysis of Financial Condition and Results of Operations", 
"Item 8.   Financial Statements and Supplementary Data", "Item 15.    Exhibits, Financial Statement Schedules"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture one or more characters that are not a number followed by numbers as a group, in the replacement use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group.

```
x1 <- sub("^([^0-9]+[0-9]+[A-Za-z]*).*", "\\1", x)
x1
#[1] NA        "ITEM 1"  "ITEM 1A" "ITEM 1B" "ITEM 2"  "ITEM 3"  "ITEM 4"  "ITEM 5"  "ITEM 6"  "ITEM 7"  "ITEM 7A" "ITEM 8"  "ITEM 9" 
#[14] "ITEM 9A" "ITEM 9B" "ITEM 10" "ITEM 11" "ITEM 12" "ITEM 13" "ITEM 14" "ITEM 15" "Item 1"  "Item 1A" "Item 1B" "Item 2"  "Item 3" 
#[27] "Item 4"  "Item 5"  "Item 6"  "Item 7"  "Item 7A" "Item 8"  "Item 9"  "Item 9A" "Item 9B" "Item 10" "Item 11" "Item 12" "Item 13"
#[40] "Item 14" "Item 15" "Item 1"  "Item 1A" "Item 1B" "Item 2"  "Item 3"  "Item 4"  "Item 5"  "Item 6"  "Item 7"  "Item 7A" "Item 8" 
#[53] "Item 9"  "Item 9A" "Item 9B" "Item 10" "Item 11" "Item 12" "Item 13" "Item 14" "Item 15" "Item 16" "Item 4"  "Item 4A" "Item 5" 
#[66] "Item 6"  "Item 7"  "Item 8"  "Item 15"
```

If we want to remove all spaces then remove the space with `sub`

```
x2 <- sub("\\s+", "", toupper(x1))
head(x2)
#[1] NA       "ITEM1"  "ITEM1A" "ITEM1B" "ITEM2"  "ITEM3"
```

Comment: Thanks! I use the following `sub("^([^0-9]+[0-9]*).*", "\\1", tolower(x))` since I have some lowercase and some upper case. Which "reduces" the unique(x) a Little but I still have "duplicates".

Comment: @user8959427 sorry, earlier didn't check the letter part after the number.  Fixed it

Comment: One final thing. If you look at ITEM15 and anything above ITEM10 they disapear. i.e. ITEM15 = ITEM1

Comment: @user8959427. A simple fix `[0-9]+`

Comment: @user8959427. The issue was that in the pattern, I specified only a single digit.  It should be one or more `[0-9]+`.  Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it. We can use the `\\U` flag along with `perl = TRUE` to capitalize everything:

```
s1 <- gsub("^(.*?)\\..*","\\U\\1", test, perl = T)
s2 <- gsub("\\s+", "", s1)

[1] NA       "ITEM1"  "ITEM1A" "ITEM1B" "ITEM2"  "ITEM3"  
 "ITEM4"  "ITEM5"  "ITEM6"  "ITEM7"  "ITEM7A"
```

My first expression breaks off "item" based based on where the period is.